# Simple_html_dom - Find first line only

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I use Simple_html_dom and I want it to show the first span.muted it finds on the page.

```
foreach($html->find('span.muted') as $e)
echo $e->innertext . "<br>";
```

Currently it execute a list of all the span.muted, and can't really seems to make it work like I want it.

This is what it looks like when i use the code.

> 3.1
>
> Version: 3.1
>
> Version: 3.1
>
> Version: 3.1

And only want it to show 3.1 in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the first one it finds without modify much of your code. Maybe you can use break like this.

```
foreach($html->find('span.muted') as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext . "<br>";
    break;
}
```

Or you can simplify it to:

```
echo $html->find('span.muted')->innertext . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result is accurate and you're looking to grab only the version number regardless of the text that precedes it, you could use regular expressions on the result:

```
foreach($html->find('span.muted') as $e)
    if(preg_match('/\d+\.\d+$/', $e->innertext, $matches)) {
      echo $matches[0] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:

```
echo $html->find('span.muted', 0)->innertext;
```

Comment: I'm voting to delete this answer because it only contains what has already been included in another answer.

Comment: @suseika - take another look, the other answers are wrong.

Comment: Right, I see now. That 0 is easy to miss.